# Use docker image in another docker image

Tags: docker

I have two docker images:

1. CLI tool
2. Webserver

The CLI tool is a very heavy docker file which takes hours to compile. I am trying to call the CLI tool from the webserver, but not sure how to go from here. Is there a way to make the command created in 1 available in 2?

At this point I tried working with volumes, but no luck. Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want do?
[Use multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: @Thomas, might be the best way forward for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The design of Docker sort-of assumes that containers communicate through a network, not through the command line. So the cleanest solution is to create a simple microservice that wraps the CLI tool and can be called through HTTP.

As a quick and dirty hack, you could also use `sshd` as such a microservice without writing any code.

---

An alternative that doesn't involve the network is to make the socket of the Docker daemon available in the webserver container using a bind mount:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

Then you should be able to communicate with the host daemon from within the container, provided that you have installed the `docker` command line tool in the image. However, note that this makes your application strongly dependent on Docker, which might not be ideal. Also note that it essentially gives the container root access to the host system!

(Note that this is different from [Docker-in-Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/), which is running a second Docker *daemon* inside a container and is generally not recommended except for specialized use cases.)

Comment: It should be also noted that sharing Docker sockets poses one of the biggest security threads towards host system. If running rootful Docker daemon on host system, container can access host system with root privileges in most of the cases

Comment: Thus, never share Docker sockets in production systems.

Comment: You make a good point. Worth editing into my post.